# PHPで連想配列をJSONにエンコードすると、同じキーを持つ値が一つを残し消えてしまう

Tags: php

これを動かすと

```
<?php

function raw_json_encode($input) {

    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?<!\\\\)\\\\u(\w{4})/',
        function ($matches) {
            return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*',$matches[1]),'UTF-8','UTF-16');
        },
        json_encode($input)
    );

}

$arr = array('Response'=>array('Shipment'=>array('shipId'=>'1','test'=>'1234/12/12'),
                               'Shipment'=>array('shipId'=>'2','test'=>'1234/01/01')));

var_dump(raw_json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT));
```

表示がこのようになります。

```
"{"Response":{"Shipment":{"shipId":"2","test":"1234\\/01\\/01"}}}"
```

今私がほしいのが、この結果なんですが

```
"{"Response":{"Shipment":{"shipId":"1","test":"1234/12/12"},"Shipment":{"shipId":"2","test":"1234/01/01"}}}"
```

どうやったらできますか？

Comment: 質問のタイトルは、内容の要点を書くようにしてください。言語はタグでわかりますし、あなたのスキルを書く必要はないです。

Comment: PHPの連想配列では同じキーを持つデータを2個持つことはできません。あなたのコード中で`$arr = array('Response'=>array('Shipment'=>array('shipId'=>'1','test'=>'1234/12/12'),
'Shipment'=>array('shipId'=>'2','test'=>'1234/01/01')));`では、`'Shipment'`というキーが2つあるため、どちらかのデータは捨てられてしまいます。(`var_dump($arr);`とでもして確かめてみてください。)つまり今のあなたの`$arr`から所望のデータをPHPで作ることはできません。(ちなみにJSONの規定上も同一JSON objectにキーの重なるデータを入れることはできないので、そのような見かけJSONっぽいが不正なデータを受信した側は処理できない可能性が高いです。)`$arr`は本来どのようなデータなのか、再度しっかり確認してください。